# Not able to import .less file in a react app

Tags: reactjs, meteor, less

I have implemented a react-meteor app and I am not able to import .less. Surprisingly there are no errors. The project structure and the code snippet is as shown below. Please tell me how this could be fixed.

[image]

Comment: i cant see where you tried to import it

Comment: I am importing it below import {session} and above For API calls to MongoDB

Comment: Are you using webpack? Any `.less` loader?

Comment: It's generally better (more readable) to use code snippets than screenshots.

Comment: @TimGivois I am not using .less loader

Comment: @Sia I wanted to share the app structure as well. Not sure if that is the right place to import the .less file

Comment: Well first. the path is wrong. Your less file is located in `../../../client/main.less` and second, if you have webpack, you need a less loader. but how are you transpiling the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed a `less` compiler?

```
meteor add less
```

Since you're `.less` file is not in the `/imports/` folder, it will be automatically bundled and loaded without needing to be imported.